# How to increase constants and setup t3editor height in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, t3editor

We recently updated our TYPO3 version from 6.2 to 7.6 and now the t3editor fields are way too small to work with:

[image]

They used to be re-sizable but now they are fixed height, that is way too small.

Is there a builtin way to make them re-sizable again?

*EDIT: I ended up adding `rows` and `wrap` value to `typo3/sysext/t3editor/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_templa‌​te.php`*

```
// Activate t3editor for sys_template constants
if (is_array($GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config'])) {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config']['renderType'] = 't3editor';
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config']['format'] = 'typoscript';
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config']['rows'] = 20;
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config']['wrap'] = 'ON';
}

// Activate t3editor for sys_template config
if (is_array($GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['config']['config'])) {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['config']['config']['renderType'] = 't3editor';
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['config']['config']['format'] = 'typoscript';
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['config']['config']['rows'] = 20;
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['config']['config']['wrap'] = 'ON';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative may be to override `$GLOBALS['TCA']` for the column configurations. You would give new values to `cols`, `rows`, or `wrap` in the `sys_template` table configuration for the first `config` (which is the `setup` textarea), the `constants`, and the `description`:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']
sys_template
    columns
        config {***setup***}
            config
                cols = 48
                format = typoscript
                renderType = t3editor
                rows = 10
                softref = TStemplate,email[subst],url[subst]
                type = text
                wrap = OFF
            defaultExtras = fix-font : enable-tab
            label = LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:systemplate.config
        constants
            config
                cols = 48
                format = typoscript
                renderType = t3editor
                rows = 10
                softref = TStemplate,email[subst],url[subst]
                type = text
                wrap = OFF
            defaultExtras = fix-font : enable-tab
            label = LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:systemplate.constants
        description
            config
                cols = 48
                rows = 5
                type = text
            defaultExtras = fix-font : enable-tab
            label = LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:systemplate.description
```

The *TCA Reference* [page for a TEXT-type column](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Text/Index.html#type-text) gives more information, and the [page for storing TCA changes](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder) can tell you where to put your changes.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, but I don't quite understand where should I put this `$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_template']['columns']['constants']['config'] = [
    'cols' => 48,
    'format' => 'typoscript',
    'renderType' => 't3editor',
    'rows' => 30,
    'softref' => 'TStemplate,email[subst],url[subst]',
    'type' => 'text',
    'wrap' => 'ON',
];` ?

Comment: Try putting it in `typo3/sysext/t3editor/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php`.

Comment: Thank you, but I think they really need to make that editor field re-sizable again.

Comment: If putting it in `typo3/sysext/t3editor/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_templa‌​te.php`you lost it in every source update. Use `typo3conf/extTables.php`instead. In install tool `[DB][extTablesDefinitionScript] = extTables.php`must be set.

Comment: @Dainis Abols -- Yes, that editor field should be re-sizable again. Consider suggesting that to the TYPO3 Core Development Team at [https://typo3.org/teams-committees/core-development/](https://typo3.org/teams-committees/core-development/) .